# how to check base url before routing using router in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js, pardon me if the question seems silly.

I am routing to other pages using :
this.options.app.navigate( myNewURL, true);

this myNewURL gets appended to the current URL in the window but before doing that i want to make some checks on it.How do i fetch the current url and then append the newUrl to it and redirect?

eg:
current url :           abc.com/firstString/SecondString
on navigation i want :  abc.com/SecongString/myNewUrl

this firstString might or might not exist, so i have to make a check for it and remove it before redirection.
How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I prefer navigation in Backbone.

```
Backbone.history.navigate('myNewUrl',{trigger:true});  //This will fire the router
```

Make `trigger false` to just change the route, but not execute the router.

In order to get the current url, you can use

```
Backbone.history.fragment();
```

References :

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html